# Connect to MySQL database via dplyr using stored credentials

Tags: r, dplyr, rmysql

I would like to access a MySQL database using `dplyr` without having to store my database passwords in plane text R code.  Hence, I'd prefer to reference my `.my.cnf` file, but since the src_mysql has default parameters for host, user, and password, the only way I can find to to to so is via the rather in-elegant:

```
test_db <- src_mysql("test",
                     default.file=path.expand("~/.my.cnf"),
                     host=NULL,
                     user=NULL,
                     password=NULL)
```

Is there a less verbose way to connect to a MySQL database from `dplyr` via stored credentials?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems from Hadley's response to this [pull request](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/268) (Feb 2014, asking to adapt code to allow reading  `my.cnf`) and the [documentation by Hadley](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/R/src-mysql.r#L15) (where he recommends using `my.cnf` and that you should pass NULL values) that passing NULL is the desired intent.

If that's bothersome, consider making a function in your `.Rprofile` with the following:

```
src_mysql_from_cnf <- function(dbname,
                      dir="~/.my.cnf",
                      host=NULL,
                      user=NULL,
                      password=NULL,
                      ...) {
    if(!(file.exists(dir)))
        stop(sprintf("No such file '%s'",dir))
    dplyr::src_mysql(
        dbname,
        default.file=path.expand(dir),
        # explicitly passing null unless otherwise specified.
        host=host,
        user=user,
        password=password,
        ...)
}
```

then you can just

```
test_db <- src_mysql_from_cnf("test")
```

Comment: You're creating a function `src_mysql`, but refer to it in your example as `src_mysql_from_cnf`. But I get the idea, thanks!